# Python - How to Increment A Value As Time Passes

Tags: python, list, increment

I'm trying to do something simple here, i want to increase my cost variable which is (100.00) by .01 every 5 minutes, so after every 5 minutes my new value/variable should be, 100.01, then 100.02, then 100.03 and so on..

but i can't figure out how to add it to my existing value. 
Here is what i've tried so far, i've reduced the 300 seconds to 10 seconds to speed things up.

```
import time
import datetime


tracking = time.time()


def values():
    global tracking

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    cost = 100.00
    increase = .01


    newvalue = []

    for x in range(1,1000):
        print(x)
        time.sleep(2)

        if time.time() - 10 > tracking:
            newvalue.append(float(increase))
            print(newvalue)
            print(now)

            tracking = time.time()



values()
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the problem, but if you wan't to increase `cost`, wouldn't you do `cost += increase`? What's `newvalue` for?

Comment: Is it necessary to increment the cost with time? It's more efficient to implement a getCost() which looks at the current time and computes the current cost. So anything which needs this just calls getCost() when it needs it.

Comment: I think what @fizzybear is saying is that instead of continually incrementing cost, you can figure out the correct value whenever you need to use it. E.g., `cost = 100 + increase * (time.time() - now)/300` (300 seconds = 5 minutes)

Comment: @NikolasStevenson-Molnar explained my idea in a simpler way. If you absolutely must do it this way, then just do `cost = int(now - initialTime)/10 * 0.01 + 100.0` where initialTime is `time.time()` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import time


def increase_value_evrey_t_sec(initail_value, interval, increase_by,stop_after = -1):
    counter = 0
    values = []
    while counter < stop_after or stop_after == -1:
        time.sleep(interval)
        initail_value += increase_by
        print(initail_value)
        values.append(initail_value)
        counter += 1
```

increase_value_evrey_t_sec(2,2,3,4)

```
increase_value_evrey_t_sec(2,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want the `+=` operator.  This adds the right-hand value to the value to the value stored in the left-hand variable.

```
import time
import datetime


tracking = time.time()


def values():
    global tracking

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    cost = 100.00
    increase = .01


    for x in range(1,1000):
        print(x)
        time.sleep(2)

        if time.time() - 10 > tracking:
            cost += increase
            print('Cost: {}'.format(cost))
            print(now)

            tracking = time.time()



values()
```

There are other issues to consider:

- Floats are not a good way to store currency values.  Because they store binary fractions, they cannot represent all decimal fractions.  Consider using `decimal.Decimal` instead.
- To track elapsed time, it's best to use `time.monotonic`.  `datetime.now()` can be adjusted externally (e.g. by ntpdate), so you cannot assume a change in datetime.now represents elapsed time.
- There doesn't seem to be a need to store `tracking` as a global.
- In a single-threaded program, values will not exit until 1000 is reached, which means you can't have other program logic running while the cost is incrementing.  Calculating the cost on-demand (as others have suggested) will allow you to run other program logic instead of just looping.